# machine's basic character set

Tags: c++, character-encoding, char

In C++ primer book, in the primitive built-in types section is says:

> A `char` is guaranteed to be big enough to hold numeric values corresponding to the characters in the machine's basic character set. That is, a `char` is the same size as a single machine byte.

Is this basic character refering to the ASCII table?

Comment: It might be.  It doesn't have to be ASCII.  There are other sets out there like EBCDIC

Comment: On most any modern computer, yes.   There are other character sets available on other computers, but they are increasingly rare and specialized.

Comment: "Machine's basic character set" doesn't really mean anything. It's really up to the C++ compiler/library vendor. Just read on and look out for the terms "source character set" and "execution character set."

Comment: Pretty poor definition since the "machine" doesnt have a character set, the character set is a notion of the tools or language just like pointers and bitfields and the heap and numerous other things.

Comment: The definition is out of date. Machines used to to have hardwired character raster displays, and the raster codes were de facto the "character set". That's usual these days, though the file system usually still has an encoding (either 16-bit Unicode or ascii). char is almost always 8 bit, even on 16-bit unicode Windows systems.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not guarantee that the basic character set shall be ASCII. And in fact other character sets have existed and still exist on specific systems such as EBCDIC.

The only guarantees are

> 1.7 The C++ memory model [intro.memory]
>   1 The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain
>   any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8
>   encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementationdefined.
>   The least significant bit is called the low-order bit; the most significant bit is called the high-order
>   bit. The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every
>   byte has a unique address.
>
> 1.8 The C++ object model [intro.object]
> ...
>   5 Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more
>   bytes of storage.
>
> 2.3 Character sets [lex.charset]
> ...the value of each character after 0 in the
>   above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

So the C++ standard guarantees that a `char` has at least 8 bits and that the digit codes have consecutive values. All other character set properties are implementation dependant.

Comment: Minor clarification: §1.7¶1 guarantees that a byte is at least eight bits. §1.8¶5 guarantees that a "most derived object" shall occupy at least one byte. 

Also relevant is §1.8¶4, which says that an object of a non-class type (such as `char`) is included in the definition of "most derived object".

I'm not sure how §2.3 is relevant however.